# When copy data from range A to range B, how to skip overwrite cells in range B with blank cell in range A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy data from range A(A1,G4) to range B(A6,G9), if any cell in range A is blank or null. don't  overwrite the corresponding cell within range B.(skip copying blank cell to range B)

How to write this script? Thanks!

Comment: sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the ranges you mention contain only data and not formulas, the following example will only write nonblank cells from A to B.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let values = sheet.getRange("A1:G4").getValues();
    let range = sheet.getRange("A6:G9")
    let source = range.getValues();
    values.forEach( (row,i) => {
        row.forEach( (col,j) => {
            if( col !== "" ) source[i][j] = col;
          }
        );
      }
    );
    range.setValues(source);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**References**

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Spread.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String))
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Arrow function =>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [Spreadsheet Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)